# How to change x-axis limit when using factor for qqplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used geom_point and geom_line to create a connected scatter plot.

```
ggplot(data=plot_24, aes(x=factor(MAB), y=IPRED))+ geom_point()+ coord_trans(x="log")+ ylim(0,100)+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 70, vjust = 0.5))+ + geom_line(aes(group=CEC))
```

And this is the plot I got. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkHtQ.png)
I am trying to adjust the x-axis, so that the values in the x-axis are evenly spread out.

I also tried using `x=MAB` but this is the plot I got. [Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwpBs.png) The line doesn't look as smooth.

Comment: Why `x=factor(MAB)`? Have you tried `x=MAB`?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @ZhiqiangWang Hi, yes I have tried that but the connecting line looks off. (screenshot2)